# Angular: read status of child components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `Parent` component with some of `Child` components. Each child component makes a decision internally if it should have a rendered content or not. It is based on user settings with some other factors.

parent.component.html:

```
<h1 *ngIf="(activeX || activeY || activeZ)" >Hello, get started!</h1>

<app-get-started-X [(active)]="activeX" >
</app-get-started-X>

<app-get-started-Y [(active)]="activeY" >
</app-get-started-Y>

<app-get-started-Z [(active)]="activeZ" >
</app-get-started-Z>
```

parent.component.ts:

```
...
activeX: boolean;
activeY: boolean;
activeZ: boolean;
...
```

get-started-X.component.html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="active" >
    <h2>Get stared with X tutorial</h2>
    Lorem ipsum...
</ng-container>
```

get-started-X.component.ts:

```
...
@Input()
active: boolean;

@Output()
activeChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
...

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.active = false;
    this.activeChange.emit(false);

    forkJoin([
        this.settingsStorage.get<boolean | undefined | null>(
            KEY_ORG_APP_DESIGN_LAYOUT_SELECTED
        ),
    ])
        .pipe(
            finalize(() => {
                this.cdr.markForCheck();
            })
        )
        .subscribe(([setting]) => {
            // this is simplyfied logic for demonstration purposes
            this.active = (setting !== undefined && setting != null) ? setting : true;
            this.activeChange.emit(this.active);
            this.cdr.markForCheck();
        });
}
...
```

Even if I change parent to this:

parent.component.html:

```
<h1 *ngIf="(activeX || activeY || activeZ)" >Hello, get started!</h1>

<app-get-started-X [active]="activeX" (activeChange)="log($event)" >
</app-get-started-X>

<app-get-started-Y [(active)]="activeY" >
</app-get-started-Y>

<app-get-started-Z [(active)]="activeZ" >
</app-get-started-Z>
```

parent.component.ts:

```
...
activeX: boolean;
activeY: boolean;
activeZ: boolean;
...

log(event: boolean) {
    console.log('hit', event);
    this.activeX = event;
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
}
```

I see log in console:

[image]

However, the `<h1>` is not visible.

If I add button to child component and manually trigger emitting on button click, then it works. I guess this has something to do with Angular Lifecycle etc.

EDIT: When I add this within `ngOnInit` in `Parent` it works:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.cdr.markForCheck();
        }, 10);
    }
```

However, this seems a dirty fix to me and I would like to understand why it does not work straight.

**WORKING SAMPLE**

parent.component.html:

```
<h1 *ngIf="(activeX || activeY || activeZ)" >Hello, get started!</h1>

<app-get-started-X 
   [active]="activeX" 
   (activeChange)="activeX=$event;redetectChanges()" 
>
</app-get-started-X>
```

parent.component.ts:

```
...
activeX: boolean;
activeY: boolean;
activeZ: boolean;
...

redetectChange() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: I feel that you should remove the `this.active = false;this.activeChange.emit(false);`from your ngOnInit, and remove the `this.active = (setting !== undefined && setting != null)...` in subscribe -use a const and emit the value- but I'm not pretty sure

Comment: try with `this.cdr.detectChanges();` inside your subscribe();

Comment: Eliseo thanks, didn't helped :(

Comment: Zerotwelve -> it works !!!! thanks

Comment: "removing the this.active?".NOTE:  If enclosed the setTimeout, you needn't use the `10`, a setTimeOut force to repaint without need "wit" 10 miliseconds

Answer (score 0):

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.cdr.markForCheck();
        }, 10);
    }
```

Let me explain to you in details why this code works, and yours does not.

To begin, you have to learn about ZoneJS.

This is a library best described as a "signal emitter" : its purpose is to detect when a function runs, when it ends, and to emit an event to trigger some observers on it.

Angular uses ZoneJS internally, so this is rather transparent to you when you start using Angular.

But one of the main features of ZoneJS is **monkeypatching** : it patches native JS functions, to do what it's supposed to do.

The best way to see that is to make a

```js
console.log(setTimeout);
```

Usually, in plain JS, you would see `[native code]`. In Angular, you will see a custom function. That is ZoneJS.

This works for timeout, internal, animation frames ...

What happens with the working code is that after the timeout has run, ZoneJS notifies Angular that your code has ended running, so Angular triggers a change detection. That's why your code works.

Whereas, on your own code, what you do is marking your component for detection : you don't trigger a change detection, you just say "ok next time your run a change detection, check this one too".

And unfortunately, RxJS is not patched with ZoneJS, so a `.subscribe` is not detected, hence your issue. This is especially problematic when you use the change detection strategy `onPush`.

To resolve that, you can simply replace `markForCheck` with `detectChanges`, or you can use a variable in your component that you call in your HTML with the `| async` pipe (which triggers a change detection).